# how to update a database with dataset changes

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, dataset

i have a table `general_ledg` with four fields. i created a dataset named `general_ledgdataset` and dragged it on to the form.
when i make changes to the data in dataset, it should update the database . but it is not updating.
i tried following code when update button is clicked

```
Private con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\nxtrading.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

con.Open()
General_ledgTableAdapter.Update(General_ledgDataSet)
Me.General_ledgDataSet.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: How did you create the DataSet and TableAdapter? In particular, what is the relationship between the `SqlCommand` you created and the `TableAdapter`?

Comment: i used the data source wizard and please ignore the cmd . i forgot to delete it

Comment: OK, and what's the relationship between your `TableAdapter` and the `SqlConnection`?

Comment: select * from general_ledg

Comment: I mean that the `SqlConnection` has nothing to do with your `TableAdapter`.